# Copy Files from one directory to another directory based on DateModified

Tags: vb.net, date, directory, move

I have some list of files(.txt) in a folder with some DateModified each.

Now I need to select all the files from todays date to 2 days before date and I need to move it to the other folder.

Can anyone let me know how do I get them based on the modified date ?

Comment: Sort them according to modified date and it is easy for you

Comment: If I do it manually I would prefer this..But how do I do it through code ?

Comment: If you have tried something, then show me.

Comment: Did you considered using `robocopy`, instead of a vbscript? The solution would a simple command line: `robocopy <sourcedir> <targetdir> *.txt /MOV /MAXAGE:2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way that I've written:

```
Private Sub Test() Handles Button1.Click

    ' Get the file paths inside the textfile.
    Dim FilePaths As String() =
        IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\File.txt")

    ' Get the file information of each filepath.
    Dim Files As IO.FileInfo() =
        (From FilePath As String In FilePaths
         Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath)
         Select New IO.FileInfo(FilePath)).ToArray

    ' Sort them by Date-Modified, and keep only files modified between 2 days to today.
    Files = (From [File] As IO.FileInfo In Files
             Order By [File].LastWriteTime Ascending
             Where [File].LastWriteTime.AddDays(-2).Year = Today.AddDays(-2).Year _
                   AndAlso [File].LastWriteTime.AddDays(-2).Month = Today.AddDays(-2).Month _
                           AndAlso [File].LastWriteTime.Day >= Today.AddDays(-2).Day).ToArray

    ' Iterate the files (to copy them for example).
    For Each [File] As IO.FileInfo In Files

        MsgBox(String.Format("Name: {0} | DateModified: {1}",
                             [File].FullName, [File].LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString & " " & Today.ToShortDateString))
    Next [File]

End Sub

End Sub
```